# Decompress zip file directly from remote source

Tags: c#, zip, sevenzipsharp

I want to store some data in zip format on Azure FileStorage.

Can SevenZipSharp (especially the SevenZipExtractor class) work with URLs like `https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/shared1/folder1/data00054.zip` instead of local file?

I want to retrieve the file from a remote location, unzip in memory, process the data, and then clean memory.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can do that even without any third party library like 7zip:

[WebClient OpenRead](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms144209(v=vs.110).aspx) will get you a stream from your URI and [ZipArchive constructor from stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh158268(v=vs.110).aspx) will get you a ZipArchive from it:

```
var uri = @"https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/shared1/folder1/data00054.zip";
var wc = new WebClient();

var stream = wc.OpenRead(uri);
var zip = new ZipArchive(stream);
```

Apply using-blocks as appropriate.

If you really really want to use the third party library, you can find the documentation (in this case, the source) [here](https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SevenZip/SevenZipExtractor.cs). As you can see, it can work with arbitrary streams as well:

```
var uri = @"https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/shared1/folder1/data00054.zip";
var wc = new WebClient();

var stream = wc.OpenRead(uri);
var extractor = new SevenZipExtractor(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about WebClient, but ZipArchive too slow and unreliable for big files. Manually downloading I'll use if SevenZipSharp will not be able to open remote file.